# (HTML/javascript) Handling a cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have a page which displays a different website (say www.cnn.com) in an iframe.

All I want, is to make links inside the iframe open in the parent window, and not inside the frame.

I know that this is normally impossible for security reasons, which makes good sense to me. However, the page I'm working on is not going to be public, but only on my private computer, and if I have to switch off certain security features to make it work, it's OK.

Is there any way at all to do this?

I have been combing through the web all day for a solution. If I missed a post here or elsewhere, please point me to it.

I read that in Firefox (which I'm using), it's possible to get extended permissions in javascript if the script is "signed" (or a particular config entry is changed). However, I don't know how to exploit these extended permissions for my purpose...any hints?

I'd also consider different approaches, e.g. not using iframes at all. Whatever the method, I want to be able to embed several websites, which I have no control over, within one page. Links clicked in any of the embedded websites should open in the parent window. It's just supposed to be a handy tool for myself. I should say that I have basically no knowledge of javascript and am just learning by doing. If you can confidently say that what I want is not possible with any client-side methods, that would help as well. I guess it would be rather straighforward to do it e.g. with php but I don't want to setup a webserver if it's not necessary. Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit different solution than you asked for, but might be a better way to attack the problem as it might give you the ability you seek without compromising any normal web security.

I wonder if [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (add-on for Firefox and other browsers) might be a useful solution for you as it allows you to run local javascript against other pages to modify them locally, somewhat regardless of normal security restrictions.  So, you could run through all the links in a CNN page and modify them if that's what you needed to do.

To use it, you would install the greasemonkey add-on into Firefox, write a script that modifies CNN.com the way you want to, install that script into Greasemonkey, then target the script at just the web page CNN.com.  I think it should work on that site whether it's in an iframe or not, but your script could likely detect whether it was in an iframe if you needed to.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the HTML5 seamless attribute would be what you are looking for.  But it doesn't appear that anything supports it yet...

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_seamless.asp